# changing position of div on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to  change div position when  screen size is less than 481px , 
I've navigation after slider almost in middle of page but in mobile view it needs to be above slider , this is what i'm try to do

```
<style type="text/css">
    .navPosition{position: relative;top: 0 !important;margin-bottom: 100px;}
 </style>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $width=$(window).width();
                if($width<481){
                        $("#navbg").addClass("navPosition");

                }

            });

        </script>
```

here is my navigation code

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" id="navbg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
```

Toggle navigation

```
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav home-nav">
                <li>  <a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>  <a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li>  <a href="#">Academics</a></li>
                <li>  <a href="#">News & Events</a></li>
                <li>  <a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

but this is not working for me , how d i get it done propely pleas help

Comment: Use CSS media queries, this is *exactly* what they were designed for.

Comment: using few lines of jquery is  this approach not okay ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: @Sikander not really. JS code should never be used as a crutch for the UI.

Comment: Also don't use W3Schools for anything, here's a more reliable and accurate guide on them from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah just did it using media query , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try media Query to do that

```
div#demo {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 481px) {
    div#demo{
        margin-top:200px;
    }
}
```

and in html side create div with that id

```
<div id='demo'> This is the demo for media query</div>
```

I am create a small [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwzhd4em/1/) for you